# forcing a definite size on a select multiple element

Tags: javascript, html, css

When a select multiple element is empty (without any options), the dimensions of the element become zero and shows only the scroll bar , also the element resizes according to the size of the data of the options . How can i create a select multiple element with a definite size which does not change irrespective of the above two factors?
Thanks in advance

Comment: set the height using css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CSS:

```
select.multiple {
   width: 200px;
   height: 400px;
}
```

The above assumes your select has `class="multiple"`, but obviously you can set your CSS selector to ID or whatever suits, and of course you'll set the dimensions and units to suit your specific case.